# Does restarting of Display Manager (e.g lightdm) restart X server as well?

Tags: xorg, display-manager, lightdm

If I restart the Display Manager, e.g `lightdm`, will X be restarted as well ?

Comment: Try it: `pgrep X`, restart lightdm, `pgrep X`, compare. `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your configuration: you can have X-window Server started by itself and then the Display Manager process or Display Manager could start the X-window server.

I have X server started by kdm in OpenSuse 12.1:

```
kdm(4655)─┬─Xorg(4671)
          └─kdm(4698)───startkde(4800)─┬─gpg-agent(4877)
                                       ├─kwrapper4(4977)
                                       └─ssh-agent(4878)
```

If you use `Unix` with `Xorg` and `pstree` you can check by:

```
pstree -p `ps -H -C Xorg -o ppid --no-header`
```

or

```
ps -H -C Xorg -o ppid --no-header | xargs pstree -p
```